# Get computer informations from Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

With Swift I'd like to get a string with the indicated informations about a computer running my application, like:

[image: My mac informations popup]

1. OS version
2. Machine type
3. Processor and memory (installed and free)

Googled all around but seems a clear answer doesn't exist.

Comment: 1) `ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString`

Comment: 2) Machine type will not be so easy. You can get only the Model Identifier AFAIK `MacPro5,1`. You would need to use the terminal command `sysctl hw.model`

Comment: 3) Processor I think you will need the terminal command as well. `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` and Memory `ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory`

Comment: @LeoDabus - I cannot use terminal: I need to get it in my app via Swift. `MacPro5,1` will be ok too, but not using terminal command.

Comment: You don't have an option. You can create a task and use a pipe to get the string.

Comment: @LeoDabus Swift can call sysctl(3) directly; there's no need for a external process. Matt Gallagher did a very nice writeup and provides a wrapper to simplify it in Swift (since it's kind of a pain to call). Just checked his code and it still compiles without errors, or even warnings. (I was a little surprised :D) https://cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/03/08/swift-wrapper-for-sysctl.html

Comment: Free memory is trickier. You need to call host_statistics. I haven't used it, but Mach_Swift seems to do this pretty well. https://github.com/daisuke-t-jp/Mach-Swift  (I can writeup full answers later if needed, but I'm betting Leo can update his answer to include all this, and I won't be free until later tonight)

Comment: (Looks like this question was closed for focus, which is true, but…eh? Anyway, what they're telling you to do is what Leo says. Ask one question per question. "Computer information" is a ton of things. You mean "how do I get the OS version" and "how do I get the processor." Search first, though, several of your specific questions probably have answers already. But if you have some left over, ask them individually. Some of these are not incredibly hard, but they require finicky calls into C APIs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ask one question at a time but I'll try to summarize:

1. To get the operating system version

   `ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString`
2. To get the machine type will not be so easy. You can get only the Model Identifier AFAIK `MacPro5,1`. You would need to use the terminal command

   `sysctl hw.model`
3. Processor I think you will need the terminal command as well.

   `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string`
   `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.core_count`
4. To get the physical memory. I am not sure if you can get the free memory as well.

   `ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory`

---

To use the terminal command in Swift you can do something like:

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8)  }
}
```

---

```
extension Process {
    static func stringFromTerminal(command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.arguments = ["-c", "sysctl -n " + command]
        task.launch()
        return pipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData.string ?? ""
    }
    static let processor = stringFromTerminal(command: "machdep.cpu.brand_string")
    static let cores = stringFromTerminal(command: "machdep.cpu.core_count")
    static let threads = stringFromTerminal(command: "machdep.cpu.thread_count")
    static let vendor = stringFromTerminal(command: "machdep.cpu.vendor")
    static let family = stringFromTerminal(command: "machdep.cpu.family")
}
```

Usage:

```
Process.processor
```